# WinDbg processing much faster than CDB

Tags: windbg, symbols

We are using CDB (command line version of WinDbg) to resolve a cab.

We are using the following command:

```
cdb -z "abc.cab" -y "SymbolsPath" -G -logo "outputfile" -lines 
-c ".kframes 100;!analyze -v;!load msec.dll;!exploitable -v;vertarget;lmv;q"
```

When I am executing the above command in WinDbg the output is generated within seconds whereas when I use CDB it takes more than a couple of hours to generate the output.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong here ?

Comment: Have you considered using something like [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to figure out what cdb is doing that takes so long? Normally this sort of thing is a result of symbol loading issues, but I can think of any reason for windbg to behave differently from cdb in that regard.

Comment: If I provide wrong symbol path in both the cases then also the "lmv" command is taking too much time in case of cdb.

Comment: In WinDbg, do you use the exact same command line or do you do it manually? Is the symbol path the same or different? Maybe symbols have already be downloaded for WinDbg but not for CDB if the path is different.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: @ThomasWeller , I do it manually in case of windbg and the symbol path in both the cases is same. My problem is still not resolved :(

Comment: @P3A - Did you try procmon?